# Any good range Query library(using K-D tree, quad tree or R-tree) in C++

Tags: c++, kdtree, quadtree

I used this library before http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/. However, they don't provide range query implementations. I Guess is there a C++ range-query implementation (Both circle or rectangle), to query two-dimensional data.

Thanks.

Comment: They do provide a range query, see 2.1.2 on pp. 6-8 and 3.1.4 on pp. 31 in http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ANNmanual_1.1.pdf.

Comment: I know this. However, they also need a parameter "K" for the range query's argument. Every time I need to assign a very large number of K for it?

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
boost::geometry::index::rtree.
```

For more information, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html), and for an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_examples/specializing_index__indexable_function_object___storing_shared_pointers_in_the_rtree.html).